# Autofac multiple database support

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm currently build an application where I'm considering multiple database support (SQL Server, MySQL).

I'm considering to have something like the following:

```
public interface IUserEngine { 
    User Get(int id);
}

public class MsSqlUserEngine : IUserEngine {
    public User Get(int id) {
        // implementation
    }
}

public class MySqlUserEngine : IUserEngine {
    public User Get(int id) {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

At the moment I just have the interface and a fixed SQL Server implementation (`UserEngine`). I'm already using AutoFac to inject an `IUserEngine` into my logical layer.

In my `AutofacConfig` class I have the following:

```
builder.RegisterType<UserEngine>().As<IUserEngine>();
```

To change from this SQL Server implementation to a future MySQL implementation what would I need to change?

Just add up an if statement which would read a AppSetting from the config file and would register the respective type?

Comment: Are you going to use both MsSqlUserEngine and MySqlUserEngine at run time?

Comment: No. Just one at a time. I was thinking there should some kind of config file to let the Autofac resolve the dependency accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Autofac mechanisms, [Autofac config](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html). Create proper configs, and swap them as required.

Comment: I realize that is the most correct correct approach to name the classes. Still that was not my question. How would I toggle between those two lines of code? Some if statement which would read a config file and register the type accordingly?